# ActiveAndroid Crash when update the app, before it actually open the app

Tags: android, sqlite, crash, activeandroid

I have been working on Active android library for database, I am facing this crash, there are some users who have experienced the same crash, the crash is only logged in google play console while there is no crash on Firebase crashlytics might be because the app crashes before actually initialised the firebase crashlytics. I am not able to replicate the same on my testing devices. What will be the reason for this Crash? Thanks!

```
java.lang.RuntimeException:




    at android.app.ActivityThread.installProvider (ActivityThread.java:5966)
      at android.app.ActivityThread.installContentProviders (ActivityThread.java:5497)
      at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication (ActivityThread.java:5436)
      at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap2 (ActivityThread.java)
      at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage (ActivityThread.java:1574)
      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:102)
      at android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:163)
      at android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:6237)
      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Native Method)
      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run (ZygoteInit.java:877)
      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:767)
    Caused by: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: 
      at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativePrepareStatement (Native Method)
      at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.acquirePreparedStatement (SQLiteConnection.java:889)
      at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.prepare (SQLiteConnection.java:500)
      at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.prepare (SQLiteSession.java:588)
      at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.<init> (SQLiteProgram.java:58)
      at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteStatement.<init> (SQLiteStatement.java:31)
      at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.executeSql (SQLiteDatabase.java:1675)
      at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.execSQL (SQLiteDatabase.java:1606)
      at com.activeandroid.DatabaseHelper.executeLegacySqlScript (DatabaseHelper.java:6)
      at com.activeandroid.DatabaseHelper.executeSqlScript (DatabaseHelper.java:5)
      at com.activeandroid.DatabaseHelper.executeMigrations (DatabaseHelper.java:7)
 at com.activeandroid.DatabaseHelper.onUpgrade (DatabaseHelper.java:3)
      at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getDatabaseLocked (SQLiteOpenHelper.java:256)
      at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getWritableDatabase (SQLiteOpenHelper.java:163)
      at com.activeandroid.Cache.openDatabase (Cache.java:1)
      at com.activeandroid.Cache.initialize (Cache.java:8)
      at com.activeandroid.ActiveAndroid.initialize (ActiveAndroid.java:6)
      at com.activeandroid.content.ContentProvider.onCreate (ContentProvider.java:1)
      at android.content.ContentProvider.attachInfo (ContentProvider.java:1759)
      at android.content.ContentProvider.attachInfo (ContentProvider.java:1734)
      at android.app.ActivityThread.installProvider (ActivityThread.java:5963)
```

Comment: It seems that it's crashing on `onUpgrade`, please post the code of your Helper class.

Comment: DatabaseHelper this class in part of ActiveAndroid library our last migration xml looks something like this
ALTER TABLE AllNotificationsReceivedNew ADD COLUMN commentId INTEGER;
ALTER TABLE AllNotificationsReceivedNew ADD COLUMN scrollToComment INTEGER;
ALTER TABLE AllNotificationsReceivedNew ADD COLUMN autoLike INTEGER;
ALTER TABLE AllNotificationsReceivedNew ADD COLUMN autoReply INTEGER;
ALTER TABLE AllNotificationsReceivedNew ADD COLUMN showCommentLikes INTEGER;

Comment: It's hard to find issue without code. Can you please check  it's still crashing if you remove the mentioned migration code?

Comment: The crash is actually not replicated on our devices, the crash is reported on Google play console. So we can't actually test that.

Comment: Having the same problem, did you find the cause of this problem?